# What makes Windows 10 1511/1607 special?

Tags: windows

I was just looking around https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/

And I noticed in the "product family" filter, the 1511 and 1607 version of Windows 10 are isolated from the "normal" version, why is this?

Comment: Broken updates man, broken updates... (guess)

Comment: Microsoft has always provided up-to-date installation media for big updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They correspond to major OS updates:

- "Normal Windows 10" is the original 2015-07 public release (RTM).
- Build 1511 is the 2015-11 "November Update", which could be considered akin to SP1.
- Build 1607 is the 2016-08 "Anniversary Update", or service pack 2.

This way, you can immediately download the most recent version and avoid having to install massive amounts of updates afterwards (which might take *days* otherwise).

This is not new – even Windows XP or 2000 were sold with service packs integrated (there also were tools for "slipstreaming" a new SP into an older CD/ISO). If you select "Windows 7" from the product filter, you'll see downloads both with & without "…with Service Pack 1".

As for why these versions are listed as separate "products" in MSDN… who knows. Maybe they felt like it.

Comment: Thanks, but a strange thing is the Enterprise 2016 LTSB listed in the "old/normal version"...